# Getting animation to work correctly with Java KeyEvent

Tags: java, animation, frame, keyevent

I am stuck with getting my sprite character to execute 2 animation frames (link_frame_2 followed by link_frame_1) by pressing the `d`. It only executes one animation frame(link_frame_2_face_right.png).

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import acm.graphics.GImage;
import acm.graphics.GPoint;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;


public class LinkGame extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run(){
        setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
        addLink();
        addKeyListeners();
        addMouseListeners();
    }
    private void addLink(){
        linkCharacter = new GImage("link sprites/link_frame_1_face_right.png");
            add(linkCharacter,link_Location_XCoord,link_Location_YCoord);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ 
        char linkMoveRightKey = e.getKeyChar();
        if(linkMoveRightKey == 'd'){
            // y should not change so goku moves in a straight line
                link_Location_YCoord = 0;
                linkCharacter.move(link_Location_XCoord,link_Location_YCoord);
                    set_Link_Anim_Frame_2_face_left();
            }
    }
    public void set_Link_Anim_Frame_2_face_left(){
        linkCharacter.setImage("link sprites/link_frame_2_face_right.png");         
    }
    public void set_Link_Anim_Frame_1_face_left(){  
        linkCharacter.setImage("link sprites/link_frame_1_face_right.png");
    }
    private GImage linkCharacter;
    private  int link_Location_XCoord = 50;
    private  int link_Location_YCoord = 50 ;
    private final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 600;
    private final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 600;
}
```

Comment: Is your game constantly going, or does it only move/change when you press a key?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment what frame to show is not being updated as you move. If you use an array of images and loop through then you will be able to have any number in your animation. I have provided the updates into your code below so you can try it out. I added a speed instead of using the initial position for your movement so you can change these two values independently. Also moving slower allows you to see the frames changing easier.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import acm.graphics.GImage;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class LinkGame extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run(){
        setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
        addLink();
        addKeyListeners();
        addMouseListeners();
    }

    private void addLink(){
        linkCharacter = new GImage("link sprites/link_frame_1_face_right.png");
            add(linkCharacter,link_Location_XCoord,link_Location_YCoord);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ 
        char linkMoveRightKey = e.getKeyChar();
        if(linkMoveRightKey == 'd'){
                linkCharacter.move(xSpeed,ySpeed);
                linkCharacter.setImage(images[frame]);
                frame++;
                if(frame>=images.length){
                    frame = 0;
                }
            }
    }
    private GImage linkCharacter;
    private  int link_Location_XCoord = 50;
    private  int link_Location_YCoord = 50 ;
    private final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 600;
    private final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 600;
    private String[] images = {"link sprites/link_frame_1_face_right.png","link sprites/link_frame_2_face_right.png"}; //Add in as many images as you want for your animation
    private int frame = 0;
    private int xSpeed = 1; //the number of pixels to move in x
    private int ySpeed = 0; //0 so you only move horizontally
}
```

Comment: I do want multiple frames to be played one after another when I press d. For some reason it only sets the image of frame_2 but NOT followed by frame_1. I tried using set_image on frame_2 then a set_image on frame_1 in the keyPressed method but then it will only set the image of frame_1 then.

Comment: Do you mean you want the animation to continue playing while d is held down? Does your image move across the screen or just move once?

Comment: The code I put up does the following: allow the sprite to move when pressing down the d key and also changes one frame of the animation(frame_2) but never changes back to frame_1 after frame_2. What I want it to do is to change frame_1 after it plays frame_2.

Comment: Do either of my examples work if you press 'd' multiple times?

Comment: it does not work, instead i get errors labeled with red text. your example is a string[], the set image method i am using looks for a directory filled with images denoted as a string. I might need to look into threads to achieve multiple frames of animation.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add the changes into your code. I have tested it and it displays the frames in a loop when d is held down. You don't need to look into threads :)